# Laravel Division by zero error

Tags: mysql, laravel, count

Im getting laravel error: **Division by zero**

*In my blade template i'm counting:*

```
{{ $user->games_played / $user->games_won }}
```

*New user has*

```
$user->games_played = 0
$user->games_won = 0
```

I getting this error only if user have some value = 0. Why i'm getting this error? And how to fix it? Thanks guys!

Comment: You're getting division by zero error because you try to divide zero by zero.

Comment: How can i avoid this error? Thanks for answer and sorry, i'm newbie on laravel

Comment: Have an if condition to check if the games_won is 0 then echo a message else continue.

Comment: What exactly are you checking here anyways?  If you're looking for a win percentage, your logic is backwards anyways.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just put a checking before the line: `{{ $user->games_played / $user->games_won }}`. If `$user->games_won` is non-zero then perform this operation.

This is not a laravel problem. This is a mathematical problem that is bugging the humanity since the discovery of the number "Zero". :P

Comment: And have an `else` that says something like "This user hasn't played any games yet.", probably.

Comment: Exactly! Really simple and working with if... I can't believe what i cannot do with same thing with my brain! :D thanks guys! +rep